# Jenkins Build Log for every stage in Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Everyone, I am looking for build log for every stage that I have executed in the pipeline.
Below is my build stage.

Stage('Build'){

```
 bat 'mvn -f workspace/pom.xml clean install'
 emailtext body: '', subect:'build is done', to:'xxxx'
```

}

I have configured emailing in the stage but it is just giving the normal email. But our requirement is we need to get a complete build. Could you please let me know what can be done to get complete build log.

Answer (score 1):

You need mainly two things. 
First, to log somehow which stages have run already. Then, you can use post actions to notify, whatever the way you want to do it.

This is just one way.

If you need to log the stages in error you need to catch the steps and set the right build log. Otherwise you can just skip the try catches, and send the completed stages.

```
def buildLog = "Stages Completed:"
def failedStageLog = ""

pipeline {

   agent any

   stages {
      stage('Hello 1') {
         steps {
            script {
                try{ //catch errors
                    echo 'Hello World 1'
                }catch(e){ //define your message
                    failedStageLog = "Hello 1"
                    error("Failing pipeline") //force to exit on  failed stage caught
                }
                buildLog = buildLog+" Hello 1"
            }    
         }
      }
      stage('Hello 2') {
         steps {
            script{ 
                try{ //catch errors
                    echo 'Hello World 2'
                }catch(e){ //define your message
                    failedStageLog = "Hello 2"
                    error("Failing pipeline") //force to exit on  failed stage caught
                }
                buildLog = buildLog+", Hello 2"
            }    
         }
      }
   }
   post{
       success{
           println buildLog // parse and send email
       }
       unsuccessful{
           println "Error on pipeline stage: $failedStageLog. $buildLog " // parse and send email
       }
   }
}
```

**Output example**

Success Message: `Pipeline status: SUCESS. Stages Completed: Hello 1, Hello 2`

Error Message: `Pipeline status: UNSUCESSFUL. Failed stage: Hello 2. Stages Completed: Hello 1`

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation

Comment: @satya If this solved your question, could you please accept the answer as the solution?